# Report Builder and connecting to OracleDb

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Been out of the setup game for a long while.

I'm having issues connecting Report Builder (and by extension SSRS) to the OracleDb.

I have Report Builder 3.0 installed and have installed all components of the ODAC 32bit driver set from Oracles website as per their recommendations.

I create a new data source, test and save the password - All lights are green.

I create a data set (even a simple SELECT * FROM Table) and it fails error below;

"The selected data extension ORACLE is not installed or cannot be loaded.  Verify that the selected data extension is installed on the client for local reports and on the report server for published reports."

I'm at a bit of a loss with it - any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Report Builder running on the Report Server or on your workstation?

It sounds to me like everything is working fine on your workstaion, but the Oracle Client is not correctly installed on your Report Server.

You need to install the **64bit** Oracle Drivers on the Report Server.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html